# Trying to call a function recursively, but it is repeating much faster than the 1 second delay in the code

Tags: ios, nstimer, performselector

I have a function that must be called every 1 second. I'm trying to just have it call itself at the end of the function, or have it call a separate function which then calls the original function after one second. Both attempts are failing - the NSLog shows the function being called much faster than every 1 second.

The first method:

```
- (void) startPlacingUser
{
NSString *bigMLLocation = [self predictLocationWith:locationRSSiValues];
[self performSelector: @selector(startPlacingUser) withObject:nil afterDelay: 1];
}
```

This one just calls itself every .3 seconds or so, and the time is not consistent - sometimes faster, sometimes slower. The function predictLocation is a big if statement that just returns a string.

The second method:

```
- (void) startPlacingUser
{
NSString *bigMLLocation = [self predictLocationWith:locationRSSiValues];
[self placeUserAgain];
}

-(void) placeUserAgain
{
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
[self startPlacingUser];
}
```

This method calls startPlacingUser like 100 times a second.

Both of these give crazy timing to calling startPlacingUser, and it's definitely not every 1 second.

Comment: Your first method should invoke `startPlacingUser` _once_, after a delay of one second. Ensure though, that the thread where you call `performSelector:` has a run loop at all. Your second approach is wonky in that you suspend the thread where the run loop is executing. While this could "work" - I can imagine that this may cause other issues. Definitely, it's _never_ a good idea to block a thread in order to accomplish this behavior. Instead use a timer (`NSTimer`) - or combine the first method with another call to a method which will invoke `performSelector:`.

Comment: If any of the answers below solve your problem, please accept it by clicking the tick mark next to it. If it doesn't solve your problem, please comment specifically what didn't work or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/) to call function **precisely** after given time

```
...
    NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target: self
                                   selector: @selector(startPlacingUser:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
...
...
-(void) startPlacingUser:(NSTimer*) t 
{
    NSString *bigMLLocation = [self predictLocationWith:locationRSSiValues];
}
```

Your current solution will not work precisely and may cause stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Change sleepForTimeInterval to 1000 it not seconds but milliseconds